# Objective-C: Переворот страниц через разные временные промежутки

Tags: ios, objective-c, page

Есть 10 страниц которые нужно переворачивать через разные промежутки времени. Нужно создать 10 таймеров для переворота или можно это сделать проще? Как сделать проще?

Comment: Массив с интервалами и реинициализация таймера по списку?

Comment: создать таймер, и когда он сработает создать следующий и так далее

Comment: @iosp могли бы вы привести пример в коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример ViewController:

```
@interface ViewController () {
    NSTimer *timer;
    NSArray *intervals;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    intervals = @[@1.0f,@2.0f,@3.0f,@2.0f,@1.0f,@1.0f,@2.0f,@3.0f,@2.0f,@1.0f];
    [self setTimerPeriod:0];
}

-(void) cleanTimer {
    if (timer != nil) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
}

-(void) setTimerPeriod: (NSInteger) index {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (timer != nil) {
            [timer invalidate];
            timer = nil;
        }
        if (timer == nil) {
            timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[intervals[index] floatValue] target:self selector:@selector(timerUpdate:) userInfo:@(index) repeats:NO];
        }
    });
}

-(void) timerUpdate:(NSTimer*)sender {
    NSInteger index = [sender.userInfo integerValue];
    index++;
    if (index<intervals.count) {
        [self setTimerPeriod:index];
        NSLog(@"Fired. New index is: %@",@(index));
    } else {
         NSLog(@"Fired. Stop.");
        [self cleanTimer];
    }
}
```

Comment: А действие переворота нужно указывать в timerUpdate?

Comment: Да. Туда попадает при каждом срабатывании таймера